# Excel VBA Can't delete entire row when part of row is a table

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, delete-row, set-union

I'm trying to loop through my data and `Union` certain row numbers that I need to delete later on. The code below stores the correct rows, but I can't delete them. I believe it's because my data is arranged in a table, since I'm able to delete the desired rows if the data is not in a table. I get the error message `'run time error 1004 - delete method of range class failed'` on the line `Urng.delete`.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws4 As Worksheet: Set ws4 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Dim LastRow As Long 
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim GroupValue
Dim GroupTotal As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim Urng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws4.Activate

GroupValue = ws4.Range("B6").Value
CurrentRow = 6     LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set Urng = Rows(LastRow + 1)

    For x = 1 To LastRow 
        GroupTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B6:B" & LastRow), GroupValue)
        If GroupTotal = 1 Then
            Set Urng = Union(Urng, Rows(CurrentRow))
        End If

        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + GroupTotal
        GroupValue = Range("B" & CurrentRow).Value     
        If GroupValue = "" Then ' 
            Exit For
        End If

    Next x

Urng.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tried using `.EntireRow.Delete` without luck.

There's no data outside the table, so deleting just the table rows could be a solution, however, I don't know how to build the loop that `Unions` the row numbers if I can't use the row number in `Union(Urng, Rows(CurrentRow))`.

Is there a VBA-solution to delete multiple entire rows, where part of the row is a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to delete row number 5 from a table named `TableName`:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Range("TableName[#All]").ListObject.ListRows(5).Delete
End Sub
```

---

Concerning your specific problem, the case is that in `Urng` you are having rows, which are both in and outside the table. Thus, they cannot be deleted with `.Delete`. Write this before `Urng.Delete` to see yourself:

```
Urng.Select
Stop
Unrg.Delete
```

At the sample you may see that the row `6` is in the table and row `18` is outside the table:

[image]

---

Concerning deletion of two rows, which are not close to each other in a table, I guess that the only way is to loop. It is a bit slower indeed, but it works:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim arrRows As Variant: arrRows = Array(10, 12)
    Dim table As ListObject: Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SomeTable")

    For cnt = UBound(arrRows) To LBound(arrRows) Step -1
        table.ListRows(arrRows(cnt)).Delete
    Next cnt

    'This works only when the rows are after each other, e.g. 2,3,4
    table.Range.Rows("2:4").Select
    Stop
    table.Range.Rows("2:4").Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete multiple rows in one go this way?

Comment: @DirtyDeffy - it is possible, but they should be all either within the table or all outside the table. Having a mixture of rows within and outside is tough, you have to loop.

Comment: I see - the reason i have a single row that is outside the table, is due to the line `Set Urng = Rows(LastRow + 1)`. The reason i have this line is because i had to set `Urng` before i use `Union` in order for the code to work. All the rows that i need to delete are inside the same table. So could something like this work? `Range("TableName[#All]").ListObject.ListRows(5, 8, 9, 11).Delete`

Comment: @DirtyDeffy  - I guess that you should loop for 5,8,9,11. Of course, with `Step -1`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I see - but the whole idea with deleting the rows in one go is to avoid deleting rows through a loop. It takes too long time. Using a temporary helper column, however, is actually really fast. I can delete 1500 rows in one second using `.RemoveDuplicates`. I appreciate that you took the time to help me out Vityata :)